# What mime type should be used for squashfs files?

Tags: rest, mime-types

In my API, I need to provide a file/directory resource (call it a `thing`) in different formats including a tar.gz and as a squashfs file. I have been looking at the "official" mime types and it looks like `application/x-compressed-tar` is appropriate for a `thing.tar.gz` file.

But what about if `thing` is created using `mksquashfs`? I am not sure if the vendor-specific mime types are the answer, because I don't think there is a vendor to specify.

Also, the output of `mksquashfs` is usually a compressed file (default is gzip). So I could use `application/x-gzip`, but since there are multiple options for compression, I don't want to have to know which compression was used since the API is focused on serving up a previously created squashfs `thing` and not a create a squashfs with a specific compression as requested by the user.

Is it okay to just make your own mime type?

- `application/x-squashfs`?
- `application/x-sqsh`?
- `application/vnd.???.squashfs`?
- `application/vnd.???.sqsh+gzip`?

Answer (score 0):

The `vnd.` namespace is reserved for *registered* vendor types, so don't use that (or go through the long and arduous process of registering this type with IANA before you can use it).  In theory, registering it could be useful and you don't have to be a *"vendor"* really (though I suppose Linux or the SquashFS community could be named as the responsible governing entity).

The `x-` prefix is now also discouraged (and subsumed by the `x.` prefix) and never really provided good semantics anyway (either you have an "unofficial standard" which nobody specifies but many people know of, or you have an unknown undocumented thing which doesn't help specify things beyond `application/octet-stream` at all).

If you want to go by the book, and don't want to go through defining a MIME type via IANA (though they define a lightweight process to encourage this) the tried and true `application/octet-stream` is still good for random byte streams.

If you do want to go for a lightweight registration, something like `application/filesystem` with suffixes like `+ext2`, `+ext3`, `+dmg` (for Mac images), `+ntfs` etc would be my proposal, but this is without much thinking about it.

Comment: Thanks. I feel like whichever way I go, I am creating some new "special" thing.

Comment: The *point* of types is that they communicate something which is somehow standardized or at least documented, so if you don't want to do that, just use the generic type they already provide for that purpose. The optional filename parameter can actually also communicate the intended purpose to a human reader quite well in many scenarios.

Comment: I think `application/filesystem+sqsh` is probably the winning suggestion. We'll see what the code reviewers say. :)

Comment: Seems `application/vnd.squashfs` has won

Comment: @rych Is this formally registered now, or just more informal ad-hockery in actual violation of the standards? It's not on https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml so it's  not official, and thus in violation of the permitted use of the `vnd` namespace.

Comment: I've no idea. It just works on my Linux. I think it's one of the AppImage `vnd` registered types